# Access to view into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to start an animation when the fragment is showed on screen(I'm working with a ViewPager).

This a part of my code

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
        private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mFragmentManager = fm;
            mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        }

        public ScreenSlidePageFragment getFragment(int position) {
            String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
            if (tag == null)
                return null;
            return (ScreenSlidePageFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }



        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
                // record the fragment tag here.
                Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
                String tag = f.getTag();
                mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
                System.out.println("holi");
            }
            return obj;
        }

    }
```

---

```
    public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    (...)
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

            // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    (...)

    SimpleOnPageChangeListener mPageChangelistener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
                    // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
                    // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
                    // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.  
                    ScreenSlidePageFragment currentFgm = mPagerAdapter.getFragment(position);
                    Animation animacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ScreenSlideActivity.this, R.anim.glasses);
                    currentFgm.getView().findViewById(R.id.image).startAnimation(animacion);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
(...)
```

The problem is when `onPageSelected` is called returns a NullPointer Exception in

```
currentFgm.getView().findViewById(R.id.image).startAnimation(animacion);
```

How could I start the animation when the fragment is showed on screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add animation to the `ViewPager` then you can implement the [ViewPager.PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html) interface and supply it to the view pager to display a different animation than the default screen slide animation.

```
ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
...
mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CustomTransformer());
```

You will find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer) two examples of PagerTransformers.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't explained well. When the fragment is showed(after page transition) a animation in a image should start.